# How to filter in mongodb dynamically?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating app that can filter data dynamically. 
If i select "John", "US", and leave the sex as blank it will return no result because the query will search a sex that is blank. I can't figure out how can i dynamically filter that in the mongodb.

ex:

```
var fName="John", 
    fCountry="US", 
    fSex="";

    db.users.find({ $and[ {sex: fSex}, {first_name: fName}, {country: fCountry} ]})
```

That query will return none.

I want the code to return a answer like this if i select "John", "US":

```
{"_id": <object>, "first_name": "John", "sex": "Male", "country": "US"}
```

users:

```
{"_id": <object>, "first_name": "John", "sex": "Male", "country": "US"},
{"_id": <object>, "first_name": "Rex", "sex": "Male", "country": "Mexico"},
{"_id": <object>, "first_name": "Jane", "sex": "Female", "country": "Canada"}
```

Thank You in advance!, btw i am new to mongo

**Edited**

Comment: Why don't you just omit `sex`?

Comment: Ye but how can i add sex in the filter if the sex has a value?

Comment: Gen, are you asking how to specify in the query that the field exists, regardless of its value? This would be `sex: { $exists: true }`.

Comment: @Semicolon,  I want to filter if i have selected a sex, or enter a name or country

Comment: @Gen how are you constructing the query in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build the query object instead of assuming it's going to looks like a specific structure.

You can add whatever checks you'd like.

```
var fName="John", 
    fCountry="US", 
    fSex="";

var query = { $and: [] };

if (fName !== "") { query.$and.push({name: fName}); }
if (fCountry !== "") { query.$and.push({country: fCountry}); }
if (fSex !== "") { query.$and.push({sex: fSex}); }

db.users.find(query);
```

Update:

As per @semicolon's comment, the `$and` here is unnecessary as mongo, [by default](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), will "and" different fields together. A simpler solution reads:

```
var query = {};
...
query.name = fName; // et cetera.
```

I'll add that it may become necessary to use the key `$and` and other operators when building more elaborate queries.

Comment: Good detective work, Tony. I didn't gather that the OP didn't know the query is just an object. I might suggest editing this to remove the superfluous `$and` query operator -- this query is actually not making any meaningful use of it and it would be easier to read without it (e.g. `if (fCountry) query.country = fCountry;`).

Comment: @Semicolon Absolutely true. Though the OP could have been stripping code to make it more terse for SO format. I will amend a note.